# Should closed questions return to the front page?

Tags: bug

Is there something unexpected going on here?

[Why do time-travel stories often have the characters "returning" to the future?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/why-do-time-travel-stories-often-have-the-characters-returning-to-the-future)

The linked question was closed three years ago and yet it has jumped onto the front page today?

Superficially I can see the reason it shows up is an edit in one of the answers, but I was surprised to see the promotion effect didn't care that the question was closed.

Comment: Why should they not? Maybe the question was wrongfully closed and bumping it to the homepage gets fresh eyes on it that might think about reopening it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot reasonable point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only questions filtered from the home page are either historically locked, heavily downvoted (less than -3 on main or -7 on metas), or deleted. All other questions will show up on the home page when bumped.

In the case of closed questions, this is a great way to ensure that wrongful closures are reversed. It also allows other users to double check on any edits, in case further edits or a rollback is needed.